# Understanding matrix property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading about matrix property from [here](http://math.kennesaw.edu/~plaval/math3260/det2.pdf).

On page 2 of pdf (equation 2.2), it says

> if $A$ is a matrix and $U$ a row-echelon form of $A$
>   then $$|A| = (-1)^r \alpha |U|   \quad\quad\quad...(2.2)$$
>   where $r$ is the number of times we performed a row interchange and $\alpha$ is the product of all the constants $k$ which appear in row operations of the form
>   $(kR_i)\rightarrow(Ri)$.

I understood $r$ here. However I didnt understood the significance of $\alpha$. Can anyone please explain how $\alpha$ is the product of all the constants $k$ which appear in row operations of the form $(kR_i)\rightarrow(Ri)$ with example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in layman terms , the explanation is as follows.

Lets say you have a matrix A and you have to reduce it To U(reduced echelon form) by using the operations mentioned in the pdf.
Now lets say ,during this process ,you have a row where the elements have a common factor k1 .So as per the property you take the k1 constant outside the matrix i.e *k1* [matrix].

Now in the next step ,lets say,you need to interchange row 1 and row2 .Then again as per the property you need to multiply (-1) with the matrix.Keep that outside too.

you go on to do further operations to reduce the matrix.

And again ,after some reduction, you might find a row has elements with common factor k2.Now again you need to take that out too.
Now you have (k1.k2) outside the matrix.
you perform a row interchange in the next step. Multiply -1 again . Since this is the second time you are doing that , you'll have (-1)^2 outside , which is nothing but 1.

if My matrix is reduced to U now then I can write :

$$A= {(-1)^2}.k1.k2.[matrix]$$

here 
$$ r=2 , \alpha=k1.k2$$

hence $$\alpha$$ is the product all the constants or common factors you can *take out* while reducing. and $$r$$ is the number of times you do an interchanging operation.

hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: yess but what about if I needed to do something like $kR_i + c \rightarrow R_i$? What will be the $\alpha$ in that case?

Comment: in that case you won't be able to take k out. so $$\alpha$$ will not change.
its similar to saying $$ kx+c \neq k(x+c) $$
so you cannot take $$k$$ out as a common factor.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant is a multilinear function of the rows. Now $kR_i\to R_i$ amounts to multiply the $i$-th row, hence the determinant,  by $\,\dfrac1k$.

Comment: But what for specific $i^{th}$ row, if it involves transformations like $kR_i \rightarrow R_i$ followed by $jR_i+c \rightarrow R_i$? What will be $\alpha$ in this case?